# rviz does not show 3d objects from urdf

Tags: rviz, urdf, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hallo.

I try to follow the tutorial
urdf Tutorials/ Building a Visual Robot Model with URDF from Scratch

The Problem what I have is that the 3d Objects are not visible. I can only see the arrows of the x/y/z axis at the joints which are moving when I change the values for the joint angle in the Gui of the joint_state_publisher.

I use melodic and I got the files directly from the Github repository.
I started with:
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=src/urdf_tutorial/urdf/06-flexible.urdf

It seems to be a general issue, because I got the same problem with other downloaded urdf-examples and all urdf files of this tutorial.

Visual in the RobotModel is in the preferences enabled and when I set TF prefix to false, the arrays of the coordinates in the origin of the not visible objects are also not visible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312706/rviz-does-not-show-3d-objects-from-urdf/) by [tommy3001](https://answers.ros.org/users/39466/tommy3001/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're probably running into something similar to #q272692. For now that still requires a work-around, until the fixes applied to the affected packages have been propagated upstream (they're in Ubuntu/Debian).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tommy3001](https://answers.ros.org/users/39466/tommy3001/) on 2019-01-14**:
Thanks for the Comment.

```
export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
```

before launch solved the problem for me.